# How to add ajax filter results in bootstrap datatables and remove the default results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have default results in bootstrap table which i need to remove once i got the ajax filter options. how to remove tbody tag completely and append filtered results in datatable. Please help me to do this

```
 $(function () {
var $result = $('#eventsResult');

$('#eventsTable').on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
    console.log('Event:', name, ', data:', args);
})
.on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
    $result.text('Event: click-row.bs.table');
})
.on('dbl-click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
    $result.text('Event: dbl-click-row.bs.table');
})
.on('sort.bs.table', function (e, name, order) {
    $result.text('Event: sort.bs.table');
})
.on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
    $result.text('Event: check.bs.table');
})
.on('uncheck.bs.table', function (e, row) {
    $result.text('Event: uncheck.bs.table');
})
.on('check-all.bs.table', function (e) {
    $result.text('Event: check-all.bs.table');
})
.on('uncheck-all.bs.table', function (e) {
    $result.text('Event: uncheck-all.bs.table');
})
.on('load-success.bs.table', function (e, data) {
    $result.text('Event: load-success.bs.table');
})
.on('load-error.bs.table', function (e, status) {
    $result.text('Event: load-error.bs.table');
})
.on('column-switch.bs.table', function (e, field, checked) {
    $result.text('Event: column-switch.bs.table');
})
.on('page-change.bs.table', function (e, size, number) {
    $result.text('Event: page-change.bs.table');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/36/